# Change values in cells based on data from drop down list

Tags: excel-formula

I'm making a basic booking system for our equipment, it's meant to be accessed in a teams folder, where you can either mark X for whole day, or hours the equipment will be used.
How can I connect the weekly schedule with the drop down list? Since I'm not using preset value, but inputs from every time something gets booked.

When I or a coworker change "Vecka:" (Week:) I want the "X" and time stamps to change accordingly. People must be able to book stuff weeks in advance. Preferably I'd also want the date next to the days to be applied aswell.

[image: Excel]

Comment: @Prema Yes please, that would work fine aswell! All I want to achieve is work flow, which is interupted constantly by equipment being busy when you've planned to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe so. Mon-Sun even with date, for many weeks. Scrolling to the right. Freezing column A. Enter Weeknumber (combined with year) in A7, press Enter and it will scroll to that week.

[image]

Comment: This would work perfectly for my application!
Är det ens möjligt att skicka PM här? Jag tar gärna del av filen om du tillåter!